# Spring Boot GetMapping 404

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I'm studying Java Spring Boot. But my get request always return 404, but my post request could succeed. I'm so confused.
Here is my Java code:

```
@Controller
public class LexicalAnalysisController {


    @CrossOrigin 
    @GetMapping(value = "api/LexicalAnalysis/test")
    public String test(){
        return "111";
    }


}
```

Here is my javaScript code:

```
scan(){
        this.$axios
          .get('/LexicalAnalysis/test')
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(reponse.data);
          })
          
          .catch(failResponse =>{

          })
        
      }
```

Here is my error information:

[image]

So what's wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you open `http://localhost:8080/api/LexicalAnalysis/test` in a chrome tab and see what is coming. Other alternate to hit it from is Postman. Just wanted to check is service is working as expected or not.

Comment: I cannot open it, it says "Whitelabel Error Page--This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)"

Comment: try making it "/api/LexicalAnalysis/test" instead of "api/LexicalAnalysis/test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either change `@controller` to `@RestController` or add `@ResponseBody` below `@controller`.
ResponseBody annotation binds a method return value to the web response body therefore it is required.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`.

This [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller) maybe helpful.

Comment: I think in his chrome screenshot, the same is being called.

Comment: @jaybhatt but he annotate controller not RestController

Comment: Yeah, the second part is correct, no doubt on that. But the endpoint is already correct I think.

Comment: @jaybhatt in his axios code i saw that but i cant understand why you downvote me

Comment: Quite the opposite man, I have upvoted your current answer.

Comment: @jaybhatt i just said my opinion without any offence, anyway tnx ;)

Answer (score 0):

I changed `@Controller` to `@RestController` and it worked, but I still don't know why.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Change @Controller to @RestController
This will do the job

Comment: By the time you submitted this, three other answers had already suggested this. Please don’t submit duplicate answers.